# .hasClass() forgets class assignments. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

Code:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#lifegrid tr td').click(function () {
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        });

        $('#animatebutton').click(function () {
            $(this).addClass('green');
            animate();
        });

        function animate() {

            var cell = [];

            for (var x = 0; x < 16; x++) {  

                cell[y] = [];

                for (var y = 0; y < 8; y++) {

                    if ($('#' + x + ',' + y).hasClass('selected')) {
                        cell[x,y] = 'alive';
                        console.log( x + "," + y + " is alive")

                    } else {
                        cell[x,y] = 'dead';
                        console.log( x + "," + y + " is dead")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

</script>
```

My code also contains a `<table>` with `<td>` elements, all of which have ids of the form "x,y". Example: `id="4,12"`.

This code returns only "`<coordinate>` is dead", regardless of whether the element has been assigned the "selected" class. Why?

Comment: So your selector looks like `$('#1,2')`? `2` is not a valid tag, or any other number for that matter.

Comment: can you share the html as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using commas in your element "id" values is problematic, because commas are CSS selector metacharacters.

It should work if you escape the comma with a backslash (or use something other than comma).

```
                if ($('#' + x + '\\,' + y).hasClass('selected')) {
```

Note that I used a *double* backslash, because it's necessary to get the backslash past the string constant grammar.

Comment: That solved it! Will accept answer once stackoverflow timer mechanism allows it. Thank you!

Comment: @user2811095 glad to hear it!

Comment: Also note that pre-html5, commas were invalid in the `id`.